# Find empty space between Polygons

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I want to find empty spaces between one or multiple polygons, a polygon contains a list of points that are connected one after another, point1 is connected to point2 that is connected to point3 by lines, I want to find the empty space that remains between them, they are displayed on a panel that is X Width, Y Height.

`private void FindEmptySpace() {
List Polygon = new List();
List<List> Polygons = new List<List>();

```
        foreach(Point point in AllPoints) {
            using(Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2)) {
                MarkerView.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(pen, point.X, point.Y, 1, 1);
                pen.Dispose();
            }
            if(point.X != -10 && point.Y != -10) {
                Polygon.Add(point);
            }
            if(point.X == -10 && point.Y == -10){
                Polygons.Add(Polygon);
                Polygon = new List<Point>();
            }
        }

        # From this point i need to calculate the empty-space.
    }`
```

this is the function that needs to do the trick.

[image: Image of the software]

I want something that does not take a lot of time as well, so, point population and check to see if it's in a polygon or not, it's not good, as well as other methods.

Comment: The list is formatted like this. [point1, point2, point3, [-10, -10]].

[-10, -10] suggests the start of a new polygon.

Comment: What result would you expect? Do you want to fill the insides of the polygons while keeping the outside black? Do you want new polygons describing the hollow space between polygons? Do the polygons actually touch each other? Or do you want the *area* of the empty space?

Comment: I do not wish to fill the inside of the polygons, Neither the new poligon to describe the hollow space between them. I want the area of the empty space and yes, some polygons touch each other.

Comment: I am currently trying to create a rectangle around the polygon but I just realised that this is not okay because the rectangle will enter other polygons.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < Polygons.Count; i ++) {
//Corners of the polygon.
Point XX = new Point(0, 0);
Point XY = new Point(0, 0);
Point YX = new Point(0, 0);
Point XX = new Point(0, 0);

foreach (List<Point> poly in Polygons) {
 foreach(Point p in poly) {
  if(p.X <= XX.X && p.Y <= XX.Y) {
    XX = p;
  } else if(p.X >= XY.X && p.Y <= XY.Y) {
   XY = p;
  } else if(p.X <= YX.X && p.Y >= YX.Y) {
   YX = p;
  } else if(p.X >= YY.X && p.Y >= YY.Y) {
   YY = p;
  }
}
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### If you want to calculate the area not covered by polygons:

The first step is to calculate the [area of each polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Area). If the polygons are guaranteed to be closed and non-self intersecting this is fairly simple:

```cs
public double GetArea()
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < PointArray.Length; i++)
    {
        var p1 = PointArray[i - 1];
        var p2 = PointArray[i];

        sum += p1.X * p2.Y - p1.Y * p2.X;
    }

    var pp1 = PointArray.Last();
    var pp2 = PointArray.First();
    sum += pp1.X * pp2.Y - pp1.Y * pp2.X;
    return sum / 2;
}
```

Then calculate the area of the enclosing rectangle and subtract the area for each polygon. This assumes the polygons does not overlap.

If you want to get the area of the **individual spaces** and the polygons are touching you could find points on all the polygons that touch the borders of another, and then start tracing the new border that is formed to create a new polygon of the empty space. But that will be a fair amount of work.

An easier approach is to just use [System.Drawing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) to [draw each polygon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.fillpolygon?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), and use segmentation to separate each "void", and then you can just count the pixels. This should be more forgiving if the polygons are only mostly touching, and you can adjust the resolution to give decent precision. The details how to do this is a bit to much to include, but [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31014/Image-Processing-Basics-in-C) seems to give a decent introduction to the concepts.

Comment: I think some polygons will be self intersected.

https://imgur.com/XmBM5TS

Comment: @NEON_GOD That does not look like a polygon to me. More like multiple polygons and lines.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer.

```
private void FindEmptySpace() {
        List<Point> Polygon = new List<Point>();
        List<List<Point>> Polygons = new List<List<Point>>();

        foreach (Point point in AllPoints) {
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2)) {
                MarkerView.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(pen, point.X, point.Y, 1, 1);
            }
            if (point.X != -10 && point.Y != -10) {
                Polygon.Add(point);
            }
            if (point.X == -10 && point.Y == -10) {
                Polygons.Add(Polygon);
                Polygon = new List<Point>();
            }
        }

        Point LastPoint = AllPoints[AllPoints.Count - 2];

        for (int X = 0; X <= LastPoint.X; X += 10) {
            for (int Y = 0; Y <= LastPoint.Y; Y += 10) {

                bool isInsidePolygon = false;

                foreach (List<Point> polygon in Polygons) {
                    int numPoints = polygon.Count;
                    int i, j = numPoints - 1;
                    bool oddNodes = false;

                    for (i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {
                        if ((polygon[i].Y < Y && polygon[j].Y >= Y || polygon[j].Y < Y && polygon[i].Y >= Y) &&
                            (polygon[i].X <= X || polygon[j].X <= X) &&
                            (polygon[i].X + (Y - polygon[i].Y) / (polygon[j].Y - polygon[i].Y) * (polygon[j].X - polygon[i].X) < X)) {
                            oddNodes = !oddNodes;
                        }
                        j = i;
                    }

                    if (oddNodes) {
                        isInsidePolygon = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!isInsidePolygon) {
                    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Green, 1)) {
                        MarkerView.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(pen, X, Y, 10, 10);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It will draw squares 10px X 10px, and check if it is inside a polygon or not, but I need to make this function a little bit more strict, because there are instances where the squares enter a polygon.